# Why the assetspack shown on my iTunes connect is 0?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

1.I use on-demand resources on my application, the building settings in xcode are as follows:

Emabed Asset Packs In Product Bundle:No

Enable On-Demand Resources:Yes

[image: building settings]

2.My app install package has a directory of files called on-demand downloads

[image: application directory]

3.I uploaded my application on iTunes connect, but assetpacks shown on my iTunes connect is 0.

[image: assetpacks]

4.I downloaded and installed my application and I found that ODR works. But I'm worried that downloaded resources originally existed in the installation package.

If you can solve my problem I will be very grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not sufficient to only ask the question in the title. Try to put a more extended version of your question into the question body